# Registers like $0

Tags: nsis

Can someone explain and/or provide reference for understanding how NSIS registers work.  For example, $0, $1.  I see examples of using them.

```
Like {If} $0 == ''
    Do something
```

I don't understand how you can put values into $0 or how values are there dynamically?

Please help, thank you.

Comment: Are you asking if they are different from other variables or just how variables work in general?

Comment: Both.  I understand it now.

Comment: I'd like to learn why this was downvoted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the NSIS Sourceforge docs, located [here](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Docs/Chapter4.html), `Registers` are already-defined variables available for use:

> These variables can be used just like user variables, but are usually used in shared functions or macros. You don't have to declare these variables so you won't get any name conflicts when using them in shared code. When using these variables in shared code it's recommended that you use the stack to save and restore their original values. These variables can also be used for communication with plug-ins because they can be read and written by the plug-in DLLs.

Variables are handled like strings in NSIS, so to put a value into one of these `Register` variables, such as `$0`, you would do a command like:

`StrCpy $0 WhatValueYouWantToBeInZero`

Comment: I'd like to accept your answer but if you could give an example, I think that might help future searchers.  Thank you.

Comment: Provided a sample variable assignment for you @vbp13 .  Hope that's enough to get you started.